# Export one attribute field from QGIS to a .TXT or .CSV file

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I used this code in Python to export attributes from QGIS to a .TXT file :

```
##input_file=vector

from qgis.core import *
import processing
# Load the layer
layer = processing.getObject(input_file)

# Set the path for the output file
output_file = open('C:/.../cities.txt', 'w')

# Get the features and properly rewrite them as lines
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    msgout = '%s, %s\n' % (feat["name"], feat["pop_max"])
    unicode_message = msgout.encode('utf-8')
    output_file.write(unicode_message)
output_file.close()
```

---

It worked, but I don't want to get all fields of the attribute table, but just one of them (ID field for example).

Will it be possible?

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods. For example, you can store the values of your field in a list and then browse the list.

```
# Append a list with the values of your field
values_field = []
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    values_field.append(feature['gml_id']) # gml_id is the name of my field

# Open your csv file 
with open('C:/Users/v.bre/Desktop/export_csv/test.csv', 'w') as file:
    # Write in your file
    for feature in values_field:
        file.write(feature)
        file.write('\n') # line break 

# Close your csv file
file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is a recuring need in your application, you could create a simple export function, such as:

```
def export_layer_to_csv(layer, fields, output_name):
    # Used to optimize feature request 
    indexes = [layer.fields().lookupField(field_name) for field_name in fields]
    with open(output_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out:
        # Iter over features, ordered by id
        for feat in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setSubsetOfAttributes(indexes).addOrderBy("id")):
            # Write the set of choosen fields as a sinle comma separated list
            out.write(",".join(str(feat[field_name]) for field_name in fields) + "\n")
```

It takes an input `QgsVectorLayer`, a list of fields (list of str) and an output path. 
You could further improve it by adding your own order by clause (here features are ordered by id), filters, and so on.

Usage

```
>>> export_layer_to_csv(my_layer, ['some_field', 'another_field'], 'C:/Temp/output.csv')
```

Comment: IMHO there have to be some `'utf-8'` encoding added