# Export one attribute field of SELECTED FEATURE from QGIS to a .CSV file using Python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I found different Python code, which could export all the list of attribute list from QGIS to a .txt or .csv file.

But, now I am creating a project where it is needed to export just ONE Attribute of ONE FEATURE (which it is selected for example).

Is it possible?

PS" Here [Export one attribute field from QGIS to a .TXT or .CSV file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343314/export-one-attribute-field-from-qgis-to-a-txt-or-csv-file) are some example of exporting all the list of attribute table

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like the following which identifies the index of the field you are interested in and then applies the [relevant parameters](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#abb1879ababb5d662ff95d7374d742008) when saving as a csv such as extracting values from a single field for the selected features:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
output_path = 'path/to/output.csv'
idx = layer.fields().indexFromName("ID")
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, output_path, "UTF-8", driverName="CSV", attributes=[idx], onlySelected=True)
```