# Separating columns of layer and exporting set of columns in a new QGIS layer

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes, export, column

I use QGIS 3.16. I need to find a way to separate the columns of a layer and export each column in a new layer named like the column.

For example: I have a file.csv that I import with the geometry wkt. After import in QGIS I have 6 columns: `id`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`.
Is it possible to find a way to export each column in a layer .shp:

- A.shp: with 2 columns: `id`, `A`
- B.shp: `id`, `B`
- C.shp: `id`, `C`
- D.shp: `id`, `D`
- E.shp: `id`, `E`

[sample of data](https://we.tl/t-6C0POQop10)

In this sample `"id"= "MAILLE"` and the columns following are `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` and `E`.

Do you know a way to achieve that in QGIS?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data ?

Comment: related [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343314/export-one-attribute-field-from-qgis-to-a-txt-or-csv-file)

Comment: @Taras I added a sample that can be downloaded by wetransfer, I didn't know how to join it to my post, I hope it's ok, let me know if I can do better

Comment: You can use [Refactor fields](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields) and drop the columns you dont need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this all at once probably is using the algorithm from Menu Processing > Toolbox > [`Retain fields`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#retain-fields) in [batch mode](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html):

1. Select your Input Layer, add as many rows as you want to create layers, then use `Autofill... > Fill Down` to insert the same layer for each row.
2. Go to the second column `Fields to retain > Autofill... > Calculate by Expression` and insert this expression (replace `my_layer` with the name of your input layer). It will automatically select the field `id` plus for each row another one of the remaining attribute fields:

   ```
    array( 
        array_remove_all(
            map_akeys (attributes(get_feature_by_id ('my_layer',1))),
            'id'
        )[@row_number] ,
        'id'
    )
   ```
3. Select a folder/filename for the output.

You're done - when running it, you'll get 5 layers.

[image]

Comment: I have qgis 3.16 on my virtual machine and this tool doesn't exist in it. I did it on my local machine on 3.22 and it works really well ! If you know how I can do it on 3.16 it will be great? If not it's already  great thanks !

Comment: Retain fields was introduced in QGIS 3.18, so this solution indeed is not possible in 3.16, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

If its only a few and automating it is too much hassle, use Layer... Save As.. and choose a name and select the columns you want to save in the dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### It is not QGIS solution

P.S. To me it sounds more like Pandas&GeoPandas task. Therefore try the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from os.path import isfile, join, normpath

csv_file = 'imp2646.csv'
path_to_project = normpath('C:/Users/Taras/Downloads/project/')
path_to_csv_file = join(path_to_project, csv_file)

if isfile(path_to_csv_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv_file, sep=';')
    gs = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['wkt_geom_2154'])
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gs, crs="EPSG:2154")
    gdf = gdf.drop('wkt_geom_2154', axis=1)
    all_columns = gdf.columns.tolist()
    all_columns.remove('geometry')
    all_columns.remove('MAILLE')
    all_columns.sort()
    pairs = list(zip(["MAILLE"]*len(all_columns), all_columns))
    for pair in pairs:
        id, attr = pair[0], pair[1]
        attributes = list(pair)
        attributes.append('geometry')
        gdf_subset = gdf[attributes]
        gdf_subset.to_file(join(path_to_project, f"{attr}.shp"))
```

and get the output that will look like this:

[image: result]

*Note:* Resulting features of each layer overlap.